# Probability distribution of a self avoiding walk

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk, integer-lattices

## Preliminary:

Consider a walk on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}_d$ lattice of length $N$. In a normal random walk, if we let $N$ get large the end position has a probability distribution (PDF) that looks like a $d$ dimensional Gaussian.

A self-avoiding walk (SAW), looks to be well studied in Mathematical and Physics literature. I've found numerous examples of *average* properties of these walks. Average end-to-end distance, average radius of gyration, average diameter, etc... I'd like to know about the PDF of the final position of a SAW, something analogous to the fact that a normal random walk looks like a Gaussian.

## Empirical data:

It was easy to code up some simulation data. I took $8*10^7$ samples of a SAW for $N=26$ in $d=2$. The resulting PDF is the top graph. The empty squares are due to the parity of the walk (some sites are even/odd sites that are only accessible when $N$ is even/odd)  What I'm really interested in is the bottom graph, where I took the average value of the PDF for a given radius $P_{SAW}(r; d)$:

[image]

For comparisons sake, the same data was computed for a regular random walk:

[image]

## Question:

> What can we say about $P_{SAW}(r; d)$?

Comment: It's not that easy to select a SAW uniformly at random from all those with a particular length.  How did you go about it?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Correct: if you do it naively, you have to reject almost all samples for $d=2$ as the chance of overlap is high. I used the Rosenbluth-Roesenbluth method (RR) I found in a paper that selects from moves available as the chain grows and weights them accordingly. http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/21/1/020

Comment: check the (brief) discussion here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602151.pdf

Comment: +1 to Mike's comment; see section 2.2.  It is a famous open conjecture that the scaling limit of SAW is $SLE_{8/3}$, which I think would address your question.  You are actually not asking for the distribution of the limit process but only its endpoint distribution, which could in principle be easier, though I would guess not.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you want to turn that into an answer I'll accept it (perhaps with a small description of SLE_{8/3}). I didn't not realize that this was an open question.